# What is a good Planned Release/Freeze/Beta Methodology?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, release-management, configuration-management

I've been working on a nightmare of a project for some months now. The product is a small Ruby on Rails app/website for internal use by a small group of people. I'm coming up to the finish line and I'd like the actual beta release to go smoothly. I still have a number of small bugs that affect functionality in a minor way and do not break the build.

This is my first job and first time taking a product to launch. I'm curious what people's methodologies are for a smooth transition to bring your application from a development environment to a live production environment.

Comment: Are you asking about how to make decisions on when to freeze the code and move it to production, or about the mechanics of how to move something into production?

Comment: I'm asking about the latter.  How to move something from development to production.

Comment: You might want to re-title the question, then.

Answer (score 1):

Your qUESTion is interesting,as it demands the methodology for the product or website launch.
But I tell you,In reality,no body follows a fixed bookish methodologies Instead they go for some Quick Checklist type method,which includes what to take care of from product building to product launching. And this check list changes year by year based on present market environment.  So I have one such resource,which I followed once ,and got Good response also.

So,Checkout this page,which has that checklist before launching publicly:

**[10-simple-tips-for-launching-a-website](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/10-simple-tips-for-launching-a-website/)**

And I had also come across one article which describes the feel before any launch,have a read of it,if your time permits at: [*7 Lessons I Learned from My First Very Small launch*](http://www.wakeupcloud.com/product-launch-lessons/)

And if wish to read more about it,then throw a keyword in google like:'Website launch flowchart',then see google may treat you nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Plan initial features/UI -> Code top x features -> Test and signoff -> dogfood/demo
Plan next iteration -> Code next x features-> Test and signoff -> demo/dogfood/Alpha
Plan next iteration -> Code next x features-> Test and signoff -> demo/dogfood/Beta --> ship

Changes/Feedback from a previous iteration can be taken into account. And depending on the cycle length you can be agile (weekly/monthly sprints) or iterative (multi-month cycles)

One of the important part is to get some kind of demo/dogfood/trial after every iteration since this gets feedback from the real users.